# How can we implement specific face makeovers with Stable Diffusion?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, image-generation

I need suggestions on what should be the exact process to achieve this use case. I have seen tools like this but I am not sure how they are operating on the backend and which techniques and APIs are they using.

I am working on an AI Hair stylist App, that allows users to upload their own images as a training set and my App allows them to wear different hairstyles of their choice, this is to allow them to dream how they would look with a specific hairstyle.

I tried training the custom model with LoRA and on top of SD was able to generate the portraits, but how can I specifically target the hairs area and put them in different poses, styles etc altogether?

Thanks in anticipation for your time.